# Behat, Handling fatal error and continue to run the test

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

I have a test suite to execute using Behat, Mink , Selelnium. When ever my test are in the middle of the execution if I get fatal error, all the steps and test cases stopped executing after that error. How to handle it. Please help.

I have gone through this "http://shashikantjagtap.net/handling-unexpected-events-with-behat/" but didn't understand a bit. I am new to behat and PHP stuff.

Comment: If there's a fatal error, it's pretty clear that test is failing until you're want to test a fatal error, which I don't think it's your situation :) so, it's pretty senseless to try go on

Comment: if i get a fatal error it  makes sense to stop that particular test case. But it is stop executing the remaining scenarios too. How to handle to run the rest of the scenarios.

Comment: Is it a fatal error in your application or the test suite? Would be nice if you pasted an example.

Comment: Fatal error from the test suite, like mouse over on a menu and click inside the menu elements.